# Use of 'a pair': Which of the following two sentences is correct?

Tags: word-usage

Bracketing commas ***are*** a pair of commas that **are** used to mention an interruption in the sentence that gives additional information about the context of the sentence.

Bracketing commas ***is*** a pair of commas that **is** used to mention an interruption in the sentence that gives additional information about the context of the sentence.

Comment: Or you could be self-referential: Bracketing commas, a pair of commas used to mention an interruption in the sentence, give additional information about the context of the sentence.

Comment: Nice one. :-) I actually did that while writing the text related to this question. Just wanted to know the correct grammatical construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

- Bracketing commas **are** a pair of commas **used** to . . . ".

It's obvious that "commas" is plural, but not so obvious as to whether "pair" is plural; some might argue that using the plural "pair of commas that are" de-emphasizes that the pairing is what is important. So taking out the *is/are* avoids that weakness.

If you don't like that option, try

- Bracketing commas **are** a pair of commas that **is** used to . . . ".

Answer (score 1):

Do you think

*"**they is** a pair"

works?

I don't, but be my guest, test it and

"they are a pair"

at Google Books (not vanilla Google), and compare the results.

Comment: "They is a pair" certainly seems wrong. I get your point. The first sentence is correct and the second is not. Right?

Comment: Rhetorical questions aren't really an answer.  You're lucky the OP caught your drift.